# How Android Talk Back differentiate between actionable or non-actionable view?

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

I am adding talkback to my android app. In this, I getting confused on some talkback readouts.

I am having a textView (e.g. `tvQuantity`) which simply denotes a number. for example, product quantity. this quantity can be increased and decrease by their respective button controls.

However, when an application is being used in talkback mode, `tvQuantity` (which is non-actionable view) is being read out as `"contentDescription for tvQuantity double tap to activate"`.
And on a separate view (e.g. `tvTitle`), which is displaying a title of some blog, It didn't append double tap to activate on content description. I am getting confused because, on both views, there's not any clickListener or any kind of action associated with it. still, the behavior of talkback is different.

I want to remove this "Double tap to activate" from non-actionable view.

I have tried to resolve it by setting `tvQuantity.setOnClickListener(null)` but it didn't work. I have also search related blogs/articles but the reason why it happened is still unknown.

I doubt that this might happen because, on some action, I am announcing accessibility as the code below. But I am really not sure if this right reason for it or not.

```
if (onSomeAction1) {
   tvQuantity.announceForAccessibility("annoucement 1")
} else if (onSomeAction2) {
   tvQuantity.announceForAccessibility("annoucement 2")
} else {
   tvQuantity.contentDescription = "contentDescription For 
tvQuantity."
}
```

If anyone can explain to me how talkback differentiates between actionable and non-actionable views then it will be a great help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, `TalkBack` will only announce `Double tap to activate` on actionable views. An ordinary `TextView` is not actionable by default and since you don't add any click listener to it, it shouldn't announce as actionable. Please [follow this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/node-tree-debugging) to debug your accessibility node tree. This may help you find the problem.

Comment: @DiegoMalone Thank you for a link. Actually, I have noticed another unexpected behavior of talkback. Sometimes it reads `"out of list"` for views which are not in `list` or `recyclerView`. It doesn't always happen. But in some specific situation, it sure happens. Exact steps are still unknown.

Comment: `TalkBack` will say `out of list` every time the user exits a list. So, it will be announced outside of the list.